# Jira cloud REST API v3 with OAuth2 - Get list of sprints

Tags: oauth-2.0, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

Is there any way to get list of sprints using Jira REST api version 3 with OAuth2? I'm well aware of this API: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/. But it does not support OAuth2.

Comment: Still not implemented though they have been talking they are working on that for 2 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None as of yet; only Jira platform APIs are supported. You can check this [comment](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/ACJIRA-1588?focusedCommentId=386537&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-386537) in this public-facing issue that also answers your question.